# Azure Devops - Cannot build pipeline agent from vs2017-win2016 to windows-latest

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

After my pipeline is run it gave me the warning below.

```
##[warning]The windows-2016 environment will be deprecated on November 15, 2021, 
and removed on March 15, 2022. Migrate to windows-latest instead. 
For more details see https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/4312
```

After seeing that warning, I tried to change Agent Sepecification from vs2017-win2016 to windows-latest. But there isn't windows-latest  option in Agent Specification dropdown.

[image: Agent Specification Dropdown List]

So, I thought that i can change it from pipeline yaml file. But I couldn't edit my pipeline on yaml editor. Because the edit page is only shown in UI editor format like below image.

[image: Task Assistant UI]

My question is, how can I open pipeline edit page with yaml file format?
If this isn't allowed, how can I choose windows-latest option for Agent Specification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In YAML pipelines there are a few magic agent-pool aliases that keep you on the supported image. `windows-latest`, `ubuntu-latest` etc. In UI based pipelines these aliases don't exist, so you'll need to manually pick a newer image.

You can [track the evolution of the images on GitHub](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/README.md)<sup>1</sup>, which also lists what images are available and what `*latest` points at (as of Nov 8th 2021):

[image: list of available images and aliases]

<sup>1</sup>) GitHub Actions and Azure Pipelines use the same underlying image.

Just select any of these in your UI pipeline and hit <kbd>Save</kbd>:

[image: Set Agent Specetecation to "windows-2019" in UI based pipelines]

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline in your screenshot is *not* a YAML pipeline, but a [Classic pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops).

Where YAML pipelines enable you to select a `*-latest` agent specification, these classic pipelines only allow you to select a specific build agent OS.

To migrate from a Classic pipeline to a YAML pipeline, see [Migrate your Classic pipeline to YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/migrate/from-classic-pipelines?view=azure-devops)
.

Comment: Or just pick `Windows 2019` for now. Which is what `windows-latest` points to.